# Need to use wusa to stop endless rebooting on R2

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-update

I installed 3 updates, which after rebooting resulted in a reboot loop, never going past the "configuring your computer for windows" stage.

Last known good configuration, safe mode etc make no difference (as expected). I have no system restore images available.

I used dism to uninstall one of the updates, but the other two appear to be MSP patches, and so I cannot use dism to uninstall them.

From what I have been reading it appears I must use wusa, however wusa does not seem to be included in WinRE.

Does anyone have a suggestion of how I can access wusa to uninstall these updates, and hopefully reverse this problem?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think wusa is going to help. Here are two options for you:

1. Boot the server to the Windows Server 2008 R2 DVD and select the option to repair the computer.
2. Boot the server to some type of WinPE DVD (BartPE, UBCD4WIN, etc) and delete the file:

%WINDIR%\winsxs\pending.xml (C:\Windows\winsxs\pending.xml).

Comment: The repair your computer option is available locally with an install of R2.

I already tried deleting pending.xml. 

wusa is the last thing to try, but I can't access it from within WinRE. Any ideas?

Comment: If you mean that you get some type of "access denied" when trying to delete it, then you'll need to take ownership of the file, then delete it. You could alternately try renaming it instead of deleting it. I had to do this about a year ago but I don't remember what steps were required to delete or rename it. Try taking ownership of the file then granting Full permissions to Everyone and\or Anonymous.

Comment: I don't get any access denied, I get command not found.

Botting into WinRE with the repair my computer option, the command wusa does not seem to exist.

Surely....it should?